# User Access Manager plugin

Tags: user-access

I have updated the UAM plugin from 1.0Beta2 to 1.1.4 (latest at the moment) and it stopped working. When I select a group to have rights for an article - the selection is not saved. 
I checked with firebug - the info is present in HTTP POST content, but is not saved in the backend.

How can I fix that?

Comment: This question is far too localized and specific to your use case. I'm thinking about voting to close.

Comment: It is not that specific as the UAM plugin is one of the top user access managing plugnis for wordpress and it has some problems, but is recently developed quite quickly. Moreover - I've got an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

Updating the plugin doesn't seem to produce the required table structure in the database. The structure has changed between versions. You have to remove the old plugin and tables and then install the new version.

This seems to work. Will report any other errors caused by the update here.